# Remove page reload on submitting forms on modal vex window angular2

Tags: angular

I'm in really bad shape now, no time, so I'm really asking for help. Sorry if my question is similar to others here.

I tried to change button to "button" from submit, and I'm trying event.preventDefault();

maybe in not proper way, but whatever. You my last hope. As topic saying, need to not reload page after submit form, code here:

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import { ip4Address } from '../validations/patterns';
import { ServersService } from './service';
import { Server } from './model';


@Component({
    selector: 'server-add',
    template: require('./server-add.component.html'),
    providers: [ServersService]
})


export class ServerAddComponent {

    servers: Server[];
    ip4Address = ip4Address;

    model = new Server();

    @Output() serverAdded = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(
        private serversService: ServersService,
        private location: Location) {
    }

    submitForm() {
        this.serversService.addServer(this.model)
            .subscribe(model => {
                model = model
            });

    }

    goBack(): void {
        location.reload();
    }
}
```

This one is angular 2 part
This one is html ;)

Sorry for WORST code popup ever - I need it tomorrow, so I'm asking for your help.

Thank you for your time, and have a nice day. [HTML](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1noh9R3awA1FTY34CeHyZ7o0jN_nPE0_8GXymVhf8Flk/edit?usp=sharing)